# Where to place master page in asp .net web project?

Tags: javascript, master-pages

I have this folder structure in my project.
`Web,WebControls` along with other folders. My .aspx pages are in `Web` folder and  master page is in `WebControls` folder. This has caused some problems.

1. In anchor tags with href='#' and onclick='SomeJavascriptFunction', href value becomes /WebControls/# and this results in 404.
2. In anchor tags href='SomeJavascriptFunction', when user clicks on the link, it looks for /Web/SomeJavascriptFunction and this is obviously not found there.

All I want to know is what is the best practice to place Master page in the project? If I can go ahead with the present structure, how can I overcome above problems?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: There's no specific rules regarding that, but just leave them in the same folder you have the pages. It will make your life easier.

Comment: Is there any way I can get rid of above issues?

Comment: I wouldn't set the `href` attribute with the `javascript` function as it is. I would rather do that: `href="javascript:void()" onclick="myJavascriptFunction()"`

Comment: As for the first scenario, I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Still it says javascriptfunction is notdefined

Comment: Than you're not loading the JS file properly. Did you debug the source to see if it's there?

Comment: Function is defined in the same page. It is defined inside $(document).ready

Comment: The `document ready` is used to attach event handlers, not to define functions. These should stay off this block.

Comment: thank you!!! that is resolved.

Comment: I've posted as an answer. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're happy with the solution posted in the comments, I'm reproducing it here:

**Where to leave the MasterPages:**

- There's no specific rules regarding that, but just leave them in the same folder you have the pages. It will make your life easier.

**How to get rid of the problems posted:**

- I wouldn't set the href attribute with the javascript function as it is. I would rather do that: `href="javascript:void()" onclick="myJavascriptFunction()"`.

**Why my Javascript function is returning undefined:**

- The `document ready` is used to attach event handlers, not to define functions. These should stay off this block.

Comment: thanks a ton. Could you please suggest a workaround for the first problem?

Comment: I don't know if that's your case, but when I came across similar issue, I've used the server side control (HyperLink) and on the NavigateUrl property I made sure it was pointing to the site root folder (~/).